# Will you still love me when I'm no longer young and beautiful?

Tags: future-tense, present-tense

The title comes from the song [*Young and Beautiful* by Lana Del Rey (YouYube)](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=o_1aF54DO60).

"Will you" == future, "I'm" == present.

Is that sentence correct? It does sound a little weird to me, since in italian we usually have accordance between different parts of the same sentence.

```
 Will you still love me      when          I'm no longer...
 Mi amerai ancora           quando         non sarò più...
      ^^^^                                      ^^^
     future                                future again
```

This would be wrong:

```
 Mi amerai ancora           quando         non sono più...
      ^^^^                                      ^^^
     future                                   present
```

Comment: *will you - future;* *I'm -present.* Correct! And the question is about the future possibility of the current state **then!**

Comment: The translation into Italian is really not necessary, your question was clear without it. If it is not clear we will ask questions to help you improve your question. Comparing languages is more for [linguistics.se](http://linguistics.stackexchange.com/) than ELL. Here it is not a question of "have accordance between different parts of the same sentence." but of having a present tense expressing a future action/state "when I'm no longer young and beautiful" being a future state, which you have perfectly understood.

Comment: The Italian shows an interesting point though: Italian has a purely grammatical future verb tense, which English lacks.

Comment: @Laure sorry, I posted the italian translation when comments and answers were showing how unclear my question was.

Comment: @oerkelens I agree with you, it is interesting, I just wanted to reassure OP that their question was clear enough without having to refer to the Italian. Italian is not the only language that will use a future when English doesn't.

Comment: @Laure: it was indeed clear enough as a question! The addition does add something to it though because it shows a possible source of confusion many people encounter whose native language _does_ have similar future tenses. So even though the question was clear, I thank izabera for adding a detail that makes it more useful to future visitors :)

Comment: @oerkelens - Not to mention that the revision helps teach the native speakers something many of us would regard as quite interesting.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Yes, that sentence is correct!

The future in English is not only formed with *will* or other auxiliary verbs. There are people that argue that English does actually not have a future tense at all!

Whether or not one agrees on that statement, there is definitely an obvious difference between English (and some Germanic sister languages like Dutch and German) and the Romance languages in the formation of grammatical tenses.

French or Italian, like Latin, can express a future tense in much the same way they express a grammatical *number*: by changing the suffix of the verb. In English there are hardly any suffixes for the grammatical number (the 3rd person singular takes an *-s*, and that is just about it!) and for different tenses, only the simple past shows in the verb ending (as *-ed*).

To indicate that something will happen at some point in the future, rather than now or in the past, we use extra words to signal that. We can use *auxiliary verbs* like *will* to indicate that (sometimes called the future tense), but we can also simply use words or phrases that describe a future moment, like *next week*, *tonight* or *tomorrow*. This is quite an interesting process, and not always very simple...

Look what happens to this simple present (continuous) sentence:

> I am eating.

It means that presently, I am in the act of consuming food. I can even say *what* I am eating, and *where*, and it still is present:

> I am eating a steak in a restaurant.

But now, I can add *when* I am eating, and all of a sudden the sentence gets a future meaning!

> Tonight, I am eating a steak in a restaurant.

This is a normal way to express that I *plan* to eat at a future moment.

If you use the word *when* to indicate a certain moment in time, you can also use a grammatical present tense and still get a future meaning:

> Please tell me *when* you are ready.

You are not ready now, you *will* be at some future moment, and *then* I want you to tell me.

Your original example came from a song, YouTube has The Beatles singing one with a very similar construction: [When I'm Sixty-Four](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=eCss0kZXeyE).

Comment: While your points are useful to understand why the grammar works like this, you should have first started by explaining that this is actually basic time concordance in subordinates.

Comment: @BogdanAlexandru What do you mean exactly? Time concordance in subordinates is hardly _basic_ if this example shows that a _syntactical present_ concords fine with a syntactic future, just because it is a _modal future_. That there has to be concordance is already acknowledged in the question, the question is why there is no syntactic concordance. Introducing big words to the answer won't help to clarify it, I think. And calling it _basic_ doesn't make it so. In Italian, the concordance _is_ basic as the question shows. In English, I don't think so.

Comment: It doesn't even have to be in subordinate clauses. For example, "I'm learning to swim next year for sure," is perfectly fine in English, too.

Comment: @oerkelens I am Romanian, and my language is the same as Italian. However I kept learning these rules in English classes that now they seem "basic" to me, and I thought it was only natural in English language, so that native speakers get it easily. Sorry if I jumped too much into conclusions.

Comment: I agree with @Bogdan: it seems simpler to me to know that in a subordinate clause (especially a conditional), we usually omit the *will*, than to talk about situations where you could either include or omit *will*, with no clear guidance as to which is correct or preferred.

Comment: @LarsH I would, in a way, also prefer language to be simple. But a rule that says "we omit _will_ in future clauses" is incorrect, and a rule that says "we _usually_ omit..." has exactly the problem you are describing. When is _usually_? Sometimes you can certainly _not_ omit _will_: I don't know when I _will_ be home. It is, in my humble opinion, more clear to abandon the idea that a future meaning is linked to a syntactical future _tense_ in English, as the latter arguably does not even _exist_. Constructing an artificial “future tense”, then “omitting _will_” seems more confusing.

Comment: I would question the 'normality' of "Tonight, I am eating a steak in a restaurant" as a way of talking about the future. It would be understood but marked as non-native. Preferred would be "Tonight, I *will be* eating" etc.

Comment: I made a misleading comment. My language is not the same as Italian, but they are from the same family (Latin languages), and they are similar with respect to this usage of verbal times in subordinates.

Comment: @oerkelens What you are saying is a valid point, but LarsH and I want to say that is it easy to keep this very simple rule: use present instead of future after "when", "if", "as soon as" (and list continues with a few similar contructs).

Comment: In fact, that is exactly how I remember it, and probably @LarsH too. I don't have a subordinate table in mind, I just made it an automatic decision to use present when referring to future actions after the aforementioned words and constructs.

Comment: You will have to extend your rule to say it applies to conditionals at least :)

Comment: @oerkelens: to an academic trying to develop a comprehensive and coherent theory of how English syntax works, your approach may be preferable. But for an English learner, I (like Bogdan, I believe) think it's more helpful to start with a simple rule that gives them the right answer most of the time. They can refine their rules later as they progress and come across exceptions. I don't prefer language to be simple, but I know that learning, in order to be successful, has to happen in chunks that are simple enough and useful enough.

Comment: @AakashM — Would you mark the question "so, what are you doing tonight?" as spoken by a non-native? I actually notice what I perceive as an over-use of the auxiliary _will_ in non-natives. My opinion _is_ no doubt influenced by this exact phenomenon in Dutch, where a future auxiliary is hardly ever used by native speakers even though it exists. But I would be surprised if my memory tricks me into falsely believing I have heard sentences like "so tomorrow we're going to London" or "tonight we're having a party" from the lips of native speakers.

Comment: @LarsH I agree that a simple (albeit incorrect!) rule can help at the early stages of learning a language. However, they often backfire later on because they get misapplied. I don't deny they _can_ be useful, but I have developed an aversion because I have seen the wreckage some of them have caused.

Answer (score 4):

Just to add to @oerkelens' answer about the future you could note that in subordinate time clauses introduced with conjunctions *when, before, as soon as, until* the present is used to refer to a future event.

- I'm so tired I will go to bed as soon as I get home.
- I won't move until he tells me to do so.
- I'll have a bath before we have dinner.

Comment: Yes, to me this is the key point. It's a question of how English handles subordinate time clauses. In fact it sounds very strange to use the future here in English.

Answer (score 4):

Yes, it's correct.  The question contains a future tense and a time clause about the future.

English doesn't usually indicate the future tense within a future time clause.

For example:

> I'll call you when I find out. / Will you call me when you find out?
> I'll speak clearly when I call. / Will you speak clearly when you call?
> I'll explain it until you understand.
> You'll understand after I've spoken for about ten minutes.

We also tend to avoid using a future tense for conditional clauses, as in:

> I'll call you if you ask me to. / Will you call me if I ask you to?
> I won't call you unless you ask me to.

A famous exception with conditional clauses is when 'will' is used to show volition and/or compliance:

> If you'll lend me ten bucks, I'll pay you back tomorrow. / If I'll lend you the ten bucks, will you promise to pay me back tomorrow?
> I'll explain everything if you will just let me talk.

Some foreigners add the 'will' in future and conditional clauses because they're not familiar with this rule (or just wish to consciously object to it).

Typically English uses these tenses for the simple forms of future:

> I will call you.  (a simple declaration of the future)
>
> I'm going to call you.  (a plan, something set to happen in connection with the present, or something with some 'momentum' leading toward it)
>
> I'm calling tonight as planned.  (an arrangement or something which has some 'momentum' leading toward it -- typically sounds more arranged or agreed upon than the previous)
>
> Don't forget our agreement:  I call you tonight.  Tomorrow, you call me.  (an established arrangement, more often something recurring -- can sound odd outside of this context)
>
> In just a couple minutes we will be flying over the North Pole.  (an example of an -ing tense, or Present Continuous, to describe an action in progress at the future time we're referring to)

While the 'will' form (usually called the Future Simple, and some people claim that English has no true 'future tense') is often converted to present tense in a time or conditional clause, the others listed above are generally preserved.  For example:

> If it rains tonight, I'm going to stay in.
> If it rains tonight, we don't go to the movies.  (suggesting that that's 'the way it will be' if it rains)
> If it rains tonight, I'll be curled up on the couch watching a movie and eating ice cream.

And we can use this with future clauses:

> When you call me tonight I'm going to answer in a funny voice.
> Agree.  When you call me tonight, I tell you my answer.  (again, an established deal)
> When you call me tonight, I'll be trying out my new pogo stick and I might not hear the phone.

To sum it all up, check out the Beatles' song ***When I'm Sixty-Four***, which gives us a question with a future clause (no 'will' there) and an example of the Future Continuous (will + VERB-ing) tense:

> When I get older, losing my hair
> Many years from now,
> Will you still be sending me a Valentine...?

Answer (score 1):

**When** is used as a conjunction which introduces a subordinate clause. In English a clause introduced by **when** or a similar construction (by the time) can never be in future tense. Yet, the context shows and refers to future; I’d say even a far future:

> **I’m no longer young**.

Consequently the use of future tense is not required, it’s understood and the sentence is correct as it is.

If **when** was used as an adverb, then the future would be used correctly:

> **When will you come?**

Comment: 'a clause introduced by when or a similar construction (by the time) can **never** be in future tense' - Not so. "She will do it tomorrow, when she has time" and "She will do it tomorrow, when she will have time" are both acceptable; they mean slightly different things.

Comment: Thank you for your answer, I got the fact that the context referred to future, I was just puzzled by the use of a present tense in such case. 
@StoneyB: mind explaining the difference?

Comment: @StoneyB, I think ‘when she will have time’ means when she is willing to have time. Am I wrong? If so it’s pure future tense?

Comment: No, it's an actual future. The difference lies between an 'integrated' *when* clause, *when she has time*, an adjunct to the head clause, and a non-restrictive relative *when* clause, *when she will have time*, an adjunct to *tomorrow*.

Comment: @StoneyB, Thank you! It was quite hard to digest but I did it.

Answer (score 0):

This question refers to a classic difference between English and the Ronmance languages. It is not only restricted to "when" but deals with the use of tenses in time subclauses introduced by conjunctions of subordination like "when", "after", "as long as", "until"...
When you have a future in the main clause you will have a present in the subclause (a future in Romance languages) :
I"ll stay here as long as you need me.
Notice that if,in such examples, you have a perfect future in Romance laguages you will find a present perfect in English :
I'll phone you as soon as he has left.
Quite logically, if we backshift these examples into the past  we will see an extension of the differences along the same logical lines :
He promised he would stay here as long as we needed him .
He told me he would phone me as soon as the guy had left.
In these two examples you would find a present and a past conditional in the Rom. languages;
It appears that when the point of reference is the present you have a present or a present perfect in the time subclause. When you view things from the past you will find a simple past or a past perfect in the time subclause.
It is important to stress that these differences only obtain in subordinate time clauses
In an example like :" I don't know when he will eventually realise what is expected of him", the future is perfectly all right as we have to do with an indirect interrogation.